# Calling REST API from Outlook Add-in returns 403 response

Tags: office-js, outlook-web-addins

I followed the [Use the Outlook REST APIs from an Outlook add-in](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/use-rest-api)
 documentation

The add-in is requesting `ReadItem` permission. I want to access the `iCalUID` of an `event` because that information is not accessible through Office.js directly.

I'm getting a `HTTP 403` response with the message:

> The api you are trying to access does not support item scoped OAUTH

The audience of the JWT token generated with `getCallbackTokenAsync` seems ok :

```json
{
    "oid": "1ae9c131-c153-4e19-a43d-7861567bf415",
    "puid": "10033FFF9B4E5A14",
    "smtp": "XXXX",
    "upn": "XXXX",
    **
    "scope": "ParentItemId:AAMkADBkMzU3NGFlLTgwYjQtNGIzMy04YjMzLTExMjU2ZTcyMzZjYQBGAAAAAAA9lyHCdsq5TIA6R2YJG5gBBwArhaEQP4FKTIpowita+cx3AAAAAAENAAArhaEQP4FKTIpowita+cx3AAD67Ki0AAA=" **
}
```

When I make a `GET` call to `https://outlook.office365.com/api/v2.0/me/events/the-rest-id-of-the-event-listed-in-the-scope` I always get back a `403`.

Changing the permission in the add-in to `ReadWriteMailbox` works, which means the flow is good. I can't understand why the token with `ReadItem` permission cannot allow a `GET` call on that specific Item.

A question of syntax? Do I need to register the add-in in some way to access the API?

Answer (score 1):

The ReadItem permission can only access the item which the add-in is activated for. It cannot access any other items in the mailbox, while ReadWriteItem can. Please refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/add-ins/understanding-outlook-add-in-permissions).

Comment: I think he's saying that he's trying to do a GET for the current item, which should work. I just tried it myself and I get the same error :|. It works fine with messages, just not with events.

Comment: We are looking into this now. Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Thanks @JasonJohnston ! That explains why it wasn't working. Thanks Marc also for the right rewording of my problem.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT do you have any update on this issue ?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. We have looked into this issue and discovered that we do not currently support getting a calendar event item using the REST API with a ReadItem nor a ReadWriteItem permission. You would need a ReadWriteMailbox permission to get around this limitation. We do not currently have plans to support this in the short term.

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT we are running into a similar issue trying to get attachment mime types for our add-in.  We do not want to request significantly elevated privileges from our users to solve this issue.  Any updates here?

Comment: @Ryan Quinn, we have some new attachment APIs that are currently in preview (`addFileAttachmentFromBase64Async`, `getAttachmentContentAsync`, `getAttachmentsAsync`). They are documented in the preview requirement set at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/preview-requirement-set/outlook-requirement-set-preview. Will that work for you? Keep in mind that they are NOT supported for older Desktop Outlook clients, so you will still need elevated privileges to invoke REST for older clients.

Comment: The Outlook REST API we are trying to use is https://outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages/{messageId}/attachments/{attachmentId}/$value to retrieve the raw contents of an item attachment (contact, event, or message) in MIME format as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message. Getting the MIME contents only works with the ReadWriteMailbox permission as the Outlook Add-ins Team responded above, but we would like it to work with ReadItem. The new client-side methods in preview do not help with our use-case.

Comment: @RyanQuinn I've confirmed that it is possible to get the full attachment through REST with the REST token returned for a ReadItem add-in. Could you post a new question with your issue so we can provide an answer for it? We do recommend using the new attachment APIs in [requirement set 1.8](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.8/outlook-requirement-set-1.8) in many cases (especially for compose add-ins), so we would be interested to understand why it doesn't help with your scenario. Thanks!

Comment: My co-worker posted the new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58883108/outlook-rest-api-get-mime-content-of-itemattachment-with-readitem-permission