# Outlook REST API Get MIME content of ItemAttachment with ReadItem permission

Tags: outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

The Outlook REST API we are trying to use is outlook.office.com/api/v2.0/me/messages{messageId}/attachments/{attachmentId}/$value to retrieve the raw contents of an ItemAttachment (contact, event, or message) in MIME format as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-get-mime-message.

Getting the MIME contents only works with the ReadWriteMailbox permission, but we would like it to work with ReadItem. We are able to retrieve FileAttachments without the elevated permission but not ItemAttachments.

Comment: There are new attachment APIs in requirement set 1.8, which will allow you to get the attachment content with ReadItem permission (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/reference/objectmodel/requirement-set-1.8/outlook-requirement-set-1.8). If these APIs do not work, we would be interested in knowing your scenario to help further.